# jQuery each to find label for attr not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an error and think i know why but not sure how to resolve it.... for example my for label / id is:

> shipping_address[country] << i think because of the brackets []

and my JS is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form :input").each(function(index, elem) {        
        var eId = $(elem).attr("id");
        var label = null;
        if (eId && (label = $(elem).parents("form").find("label[for="+eId+"]")).length == 1) {
            $(elem).attr("placeholder", $(label).html());
            $(label).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Error:

> js__jquery.js?1419646…:1468 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized
>   expression: label[for=billing_address[first_name]]

Example HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="card[first_name]">First Name<span>    *     </span></label>

        <input id="card[first_name]" name="card[first_name]" type="text" class="form-control" value="" validate="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please add the html code.

Comment: You need to escape `[` and `]` inside the attribute selector.

Comment: Sorry added HTML and new to JS so trial and error for me :)

Comment: @Satpal Yes they can. HTML5 removed all the character restrictions on IDs.

Comment: `(eId && (label = $(elem).` is a bad coding way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the attribute value within quotes or escape metacharacter since the id value contains some metacharacter which has special meaning in jQuery.

```
.find("label[for='" + eId + "']")
//              -^-----------^-
```

---

From [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) :

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar"). The W3C CSS specification contains the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS selectors. Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on CSS character escape sequences for identifiers.

---

**FYI :** Use [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method instead of [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html) method to get text content.

```
$(elem).attr("placeholder", $(label).text());
//                             ------^^^^^^---
```

Comment: Worked a treat! its adding in the <span></span> html - just looking on how to resolve that now :)

Comment: Before I convert from html to text is there a way to remove whitespace from the span as it currently is like <span>     *    </span> and would be nice to clean that so <span>*</span> then output as text... thanks for all your help.

Comment: @JamesBrandon: `$(label).find('span').html(function(i,htm){ return htm.trim(); }).end().text()`

Comment: Thanks mate, think its down to line breaks now looking at it from applying that fix. Doing a google to see if can resolve this :)

Comment: .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"") removed line break but whitespace not trimming it seems... checking it out and will let you know

Comment: @JamesBrandon :  try `.replace(/\s+/g,' ')`

Comment: Tried, think it is working but looking at it think might be after the label text before the span looking at the source... just looking.

Comment: test.html:1528 First Name ----------- <span>*</span>    
test.html:1532 First Name ----------- *

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145119/discussion-between-james-brandon-and-pranav-c-balan).

Comment: @JamesBrandon :  `$(label).contents().map(function(){ return $(this).text().trim(); }).get().join('')`

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets inside attribute selectors need to be escaped.

```
var eId = elem.id.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
```

Comment: or `var eId = elem.id.replace(/\[|\]/g, '\\$&');`